# Using Java to Add the Contents of two EditText views in Android

Tags: java, android

I have a toy app that contains:

- `editText1` for entering a number. Uses `inputType` of `number`.
- `editText2` for entering a second number. Uses `inputType` of `number`.
- `adderButton` for triggering addition.
- `textVeiw`  for displaying the result of the addition.

I know:

- The naming could be better
- I should check for overflow/underflow on the addition and elsewhere.

This code is working for simple cases.

```
 public void adder_click(View view) {
        EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        EditText et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        Integer s = Integer.valueOf(et1.getText().toString()) + Integer.valueOf(et2.getText().toString());
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tv.setText(s.toString());   
    }
```

Is there a more direct way of reading the values and performing the addition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that's as direct as it's going to be with an `EditText` (you could try it with a [`NumberPicker`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html)), as you cannot directly get an integer from it.

But you could extract the process into its own method:

```
private int getInt(EditText editText) throws NumberFormatException {
    return Integer.valueOf(editText.getText().toString());
}
```

If you also use what [@mleyfman](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/60606/47450) said, your code would look like this:

```
public void adder_click() {
    tv.setText(getInt(et1) + getInt(et2));   
}
```

Also note that I removed the method argument, as it's unused.

And for the record, yes, the naming isn't very good. It's easy to just leave the names as `editText1`, `editText2`, etc, but this will get confusing really fast (as will `tv`, `et1`, `et2`, etc). Also, use camelCase (`adder_click` should be `adderClick`)

Answer (score 6):

That code is a bit dangerous. `Integer.valueOf()` can throw `NumberFormatException` which you make no effort to catch. This will happen if you have commas in numbers or non-digit characters. Your other comments are also very important.

As for simplifying the method, it is not good that you call `findViewById` 3 times every time you press a button. I would store references to `editText1`, `editText2` and `textView` externally (of this method), as then you can reuse all three here and elsewhere in your code with subtract/multiply etc. You can then remove three lines of code and just have:

```
Integer s = Integer.valueOf(et1.getText().toString()) + Integer.valueOf(et2.getText().toString());
tv.setText(s.toString());
```

Remember that you should probably wrap the code in a try catch block unless you can guarantee the text field will only contain decimal numbers. Also, add in your overflow/underflow logic as well.

Comment: For `edtitText1` and `editText2` the `inputType` is set to `number` in the activity's XML. So only digits can be input from the onscreen keyboard in the emulator. But could non-digits be pasted into the text field? I am using Android Studio if this context doesn't make sense in Eclipse or another development environment.

Comment: If that is the case, then the code is safe. If at some point someone touches the XML and removes that, then the code might blow up then. In general, I always code with the philosophy: better safe than sorry, so that is why I urge you to be diligent.

Comment: I appreciate the wisdom. The adder program was literally just my very first attempt to wire up an event. And so I stumbled blindly into the the realization that I had to use reflection.

Comment: @benrudgers you could also add checks like `if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(et1.getText().toString())){//do something}` to check emptiness